# lmsensors doesn't detect my fan. How should I control my fanspeed?

Tags: drivers, fan, fancontrol, sensors, amd-graphics

I first used `sudo sensors-detect` and the result is as follows:

```
Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `k10temp' (autoloaded):
  * Chip `AMD Family 16h thermal sensors' (confidence: 9)

No modules to load, skipping modules configuration.

Unloading cpuid... OK
```

Since there are no modules to load, I didn't restart any service and ran this command: `sudo pwmconfig`. Now it says that there are no capable sensor modules.

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

I'm using HP 15T Touchsmart notebook.
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)
CPU: AMD A4-6210 APU with AMD Radeon R3 Graphics
RAM: 4GB

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question... Not all systems have `pwm-capable` sensors, if you want one you have to physically install one...

Comment: Is there any other way to control my fan speed (Other than physical installation)?

Comment: It all depends on the hardware. Try to look for the manual and see what are the available options that the producer gave you. On some systems it works out-of-the-box (I have wonderful experience with Dell+Intel+Nvidia) , but it really depends on the hardware that you have. And since you have AMD, and AMD does not support Linux with the proprietary drivers anymore, I would not be so confident that you will find a solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

The HP 15T Touchsmart notebook with an AMD processor uses the AMD A76 chipset and it does not appear`lm-sensors` supports this.

Your fan speed is controlled by your UEFI BIOS.

You can set the fan to be permanently on within the BIOS. This option is within system configuration options.

It will be worth installing tlp or laptop-mode-tools to reduce your power consumption and hence cpu tempature.

Comment: I searched in the BIOS but didn't find anything related to it. Actually my fan is not working at full speed (or atleast optimal speed) even when notebook heats a lot. I want it to rotate at higher speed.

Comment: @ JyotishP Can you take photos of each of the pages of the BIOS and post them on an application like photobucket and edit your questuion to provide a link? Does your laptop have CoolSense? Add a comment starting @SteveRoome so I get notified when you do.